# WPF Custom Control Creation.?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I am right now working with a WPF application where I have to write my Own Custom Control For DateTime Picker.
The DateTime Picker does not have any provision to Set the userdefine Date Format.

What is the Approch to do this..If any one having any Idea Please help me.

Thanks 
Arijit.

---

User Define Format means..
in my senarion I have a configuration file and I have n number of Axes where date time will be displaied and I have a dropdown which will show the current date in the format that is configured in a config file.Now for each axis the format in the config file may be different and in this senarion I want the date picker should be populated with that format of the axis which is currently selected.

now the problem is that I have already tried with the the following approch what @Sebastian Edelmeier  had already pointed but

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
ci.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

as I will be Changing the Culture of the Application Of changing of the Dropdown ,that way is not acceptable.and moreover The control is a dialog that once the current thread is updated it was not reverting back to another culture i guess.

I am totally stuck at time point.

Comment: what do you mean with "userdefined Date Format"? the format the datetime is displayed? i guess this can be done using a custom controltemplate with the existing DateTime picker adding e.g. a converter to the output textblock.

Comment: Joachim Could u please show me a code for that control templete which will solve my issue.please..!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could overwrite the DatePickerTextBox´s ControlTemplate with a StringFormat Parameter in the Binding. e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
              <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" 
                   Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat=\{0:f\}}" />
              </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

where {0:f} is the desired string format. Alternatively you could use a custom converter to get the format you desired.
I guess this might be enough so you don´t have to overwrite the controltemplate for the whole datepicker

Answer (score -1):

If you want all the functionality and only change the way the date is described, you can just edit your CultureInfo :

```
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
 ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
 ci.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This seems very invasive when a simple ValueConverter would do the trick.

Comment: please, Mister, show us how a ValueConverter would do the trick...He doesn't want to convert the date to a string or treat it differently, but only change the way it is depicted in the control...

Comment: @ jjrdk and @SebastianEdelmeier I don't want to go with the String conversion approch, because I have localization in my application and on changing of the location or we will found different time format that will create lots of issue which I had already faced.
Thanking you.
Arijit

Comment: You don't even have to change the Thread's culture, it will do to create a locale like the one mentioned above and assign it to the control in question...

Comment: A ValueConverter works if you use the default DateTime.Parse and DateTime.ToShortDateString. Then it's also culture independant